# How to implement a text field formatter that renders a URL as the image?

Tags: 8, hooks

If a node has a text field with the url of an image as its value, how can I render this field as the image?

The image does exists it will be given the image url. I have to write that url into the text field.

Now using this url the value of this field should be an image when the node is viewed. But should be again editable textfield when editing the node.

And if in case the image doesn't exits a string can be shown "no image available".

Comment: Arpitk welcome to the Drupal stackexchange. Please edit your question and make it a little clearer.  The image exists already ? You want the image text to be replaced by an equivalent image ? Would greatly help to give a specific example.

Comment: Hi @GiorgosK thanks for the quick reply. Yes the image does exists i will be given the image url. I have to write that url into the text field. Now using this url the value of this field should be an image when the node is viewed. But should be again editable textfiled when editing the node And if in case the image doesnt exits a string can be shown "no image available". i am working on drupal 8

Comment: Please reformat the question with these details.

Comment: Have you reviewed the Field Formatter example at Drupal.org (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the [Drupal.org example](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/creating-custom-field-types-widgets-and-formatters/create-a-custom-0) on creating a custom Field Formatter. Inside the viewElements function, you can add an if statement to check if the remote file exist. If it does, assign the url to the markup. If not, assign some text:

```
viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode) {
    $element = [];

    foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
        $file = $item->value;
        $file_headers = @get_headers($file);
        if(!$file_headers || $file_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
            $url = Url::fromUserInput($file);
            $markup = "<img src={$url->toUriString()} \>";
        }
        else {
            $markup= "File Not Found";
        }
      // Render each element as markup.
      $element[$delta] = ['#markup' => $markup];
    }

    return $element;
  }
```

Part of this answer is from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280394/how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-via-php).
I have not tested this, but it should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Use a view to display this content type. Then set the view to display fields.

You can then add the text field and then add a template for this specific field.

You can technically override the output of the field and put the html there, but it's bad practice to put html into the database. So I would stick with doing it with a view template file. Then you can also put in an alt tag from the title field or wherever. The only issue is you won't have the image height/width which is best practice to include, you could use some fancy javascript to do this but it may not be worth the cost.

Drupal.org documentation on views template naming: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/group/views_templates/8.2.x